# Scores from Stanza annotations

Tags: stanford-nlp

Is there any way to extract confidence scores for (e.g) the dependency parse tag of a specific token from a Stanza annotation? I think this is possible using the CoreNLP interface, but I've not been able to find any similar functionality within Stanza itself.